# Is it possible to use a third party as an external source for Journey Builder via API?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, journeybuilder, heroku

I understand that you can fire an event using API to start an interaction in Journey Builder.

But is it possible, via API, to start a journey and inject records from a third party source (e.g. records from Heroku)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes of course. You'd need to use the [Events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postEvent.htm) method to achieve this.

The name/value pairs that you include in the `data` object of your payload will be serialized into your Event Source Data Extension and the Event will be fired, causing the Contact to enter the Journey (providing they meet the Contact Filter Criteria defined for the event).

Note, the documented example uses `ContactID`, but you would most likely use `ContactKey` as `ContactID` is a system defined identifier which you would only use if the Contact already exists and you happened to know this value.

Comment: Does it mean that I still need to create a Journey Builder Trigger (via App Center) and a Data extension to accomplish all these?

Comment: You certainly don't need to create a Journey Builder Trigger in App Center. You will need to create an app, but for the purposes of obtaining OAuth credentials, so you can obtain an accessToken for use in your request. You will need to create a Data Extension to use as your Event Source DE (within a Contact Data Event), which will be used to serialize the data from your request.

Comment: This is pretty straightforward to accomplish but there are a few pitfalls if you are not familiar with configuring journeys. If you get stuck I'd be happy to assist offline, you can drop me an email eliot.harper[at]salesforcemvps.com and I will setup a brief webinar to walk you through the process.

Comment: This is becoming clear to me now as I'm getting the idea of how to set it up. I will drop you a line if ever I get stuck on setting it up. Your input was very much helpful. Thanks!